# Play AVAudio Player and AVCam at the same time

Tags: ios, multithreading, avaudioplayer, avcam

I am using the AVCam by apple and I am having difficulty running *AVAudioPlayer* while *AVCam* is running. What shouLd I do? One of them stops every time I run them at the same time. *AVCam* is running using **dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{});** while *AVAudioPlayer* is in the main queue. Please help me! I need a help!

Comment: I tried removing the "audioInput" and it worked! but the audio in the video is muted. what should i do guys?

Comment: I got it. Just add an audio session.

Answer (score 1):

Import the following

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>
```

Use following line of code in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingwithOptions

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```